# Issue with nodejs validatorjs async callbacks

Tags: node.js, callback

Does anyone use validatorjs. I am not sure if their is an issue with the async callbacks.

If I have an await inside a the callback custom validator function, the validator passes attribute doesnt work.

If the passes method passes(false, 'error') is called before the await then it works.

Here is the sample code i am using.

```
const Validator = require('validatorjs');

Validator.registerAsync('exists', func, '');

let data = {
  name: 'passe',
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  age: 28
};

let rules = {
  name: 'required|exists:1,2,3',
  email: 'required|email',
  age: 'min:18'
};

let validation = new Validator(data, rules);
validation.hasAsync = true; 

validation.checkAsync(() => {}, () => {});

console.log(validation.errors.all());


async function func(value, attribute, req, passes) {
  // Just to test using an await method
  const p = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(1);
  });

  if (value === 'passes') {
    return passes();
  }

  return passes(false, 'Not found');
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What does `console.log(validation.errors.all());` returns?

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to add your checks inside `checkAsync` callbacks.

```
validation.checkAsync(() => {
    //callback runs if validation passes
}, () => {
    //callback runs if validation fails
    console.log(validation.errors.all());
});
```

Check [this part of the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs#asynchronous-validation) for more.

Second, it's better to return the promise in its own function then use await with what returned:

```
async function func(value, attribute, req, passes) {
    const p = await (function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (value === 'passes') {
                resolve(passes());
            }

            resolve(passes(false, 'Not found'));
        });

    });
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, It works, as expected, although I found a different approach.

Comment: @MaximusN Great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function below to listen validation result as Promise response:

```
function checkAsync (validator) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function passes () {
        resolve()
      }

      function fails () {
        reject(validator.errors.all())
      }

      validator.checkAsync(passes, fails)
    })
  }
```